# copy sets of numbers into a listbox from a textbox

Tags: vba

I have a textbox that the user puts in sets of numbers(e.g. 32  45  98  56  52 1 23) and I need to copy these numbers into a listbox so that each number is its own item. So far I have this

```
         For Each ch As Char In TextBox20.Text
            If Char.IsDigit(ch) Then
                ListBox1.Items.Add(ch)
            End If
        Next
```

but the problem is that it will copy each digit as an item so we will end up with

```
3
2
4
5
9
8
5 
6
```

I need it to copy them like this

```
32
45
98
56
```

Comment: if each number is seperated by a space then split the line of text on spaces and add each element of that array to your list box.

Comment: I had thought of that; however, I cannot find any code that allows me to do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here is a sample of how to do that

```
Sub addToListBox()
Dim sample As String
Dim v As Variant
Dim i As Integer

sample = "32 45 98 56 52 1 23"

v = Split(sample, " ")

For i = 0 To UBound(v)
    If IsNumeric(v(i)) Then
        ListBox1.Items.Add(v(i))
    End If

Next i

End Sub
```